What is this TC1032F, 2-lead blue disc component?

A centipede shorted out my Samsung A/C PCB and it looks like this component has burnt off. I want to replace it but can't seem to find a replacement or how to read it with googling.
Can anybody help me identify what it is exactly and what its rated for?
Best guess is its a MOV varistor but it has 0.010 microfarads on it when tested with a multimeter so I'm not sure?

While the question title contains TC1032F, from the picture the actual marking appears to be SC1032F.

That's a safety capacitor, Class X1/Y2, rated for 250V AC, 10nF. Given that it still reads 0.01µF (10nF), it seems that while it's physically damaged, it's still somewhat functional. You should replace it anyway as it's potentially safety-critical.

Great! Thanks heaps for that! The code really threw me off as it had multiple numbers an letters, couldn't find anywhere online about a ZF tolerance. Thanks again
